# Convert .dict to array

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary

how can i convert entries from a .dict file like:

> ```
> aveu
>     acknowledgement, admission
> ```

to an php array like

> $array['aveu'] = array( 1 => 'acknowledgement', 2 => 'admission');

thanks for any help!

Comment: This is a very small [mcve] -- perhaps too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the parent has no whitespace before it, and the child records are comma-separated beginning with whitespace, loop over the lines in the file. If there's no whitespace at the front (via `preg_match()`), start a new array key and `explode()` the subsequent whitespace lines.

```
$output = array();
$lines = file('yourfile.dict');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  // Skip blank lines
  if (strlen(trim($line)) > 0) {
    // No leading whitespace, start a new key:
    if (!preg_match('/^\s+/', $line)) {
      $key = trim($line);
      $output[$key] = array();
    }
    // Otherwise, explode and add to the previous $key (if $key is non-empty)
    else if (!empty($key)) {
      $terms = explode(",", $line);
      // Trim off whitespace
      $terms = array_map('trim', $terms);
      // Merge them onto the existing key (if multiple lines)
      $output[$key] = array_merge($output[$key], $terms);
    }
    else {
      // Error - no current $key
      echo "??? We don't have an active key.";
    }
  }
}
```